# Multiple versions of the same multi-modules maven project under eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I'd like to work on **two different versions** of the **same multi-modules maven project** under eclipse.

Unfortunately, when you import a multi-module maven project under eclipse, you can change the **parent module** project name yourself, to prevent conflicts, but **not the child modules projects names**. Child modules are imported as root projects, named after the module name. Apparently there is no way to rename them during import.

In an ideal scenario, I'd like to **keep the pom as it is**. Obviously I'd like to keep the **same eclipse workspace**...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to change the name pattern in the m2eclipse importer. All modules will have this pattern and you have a conflict-free env.

Comment: Wow, great answer. I did not know that. So far I have always opted for a different workspace or have used the switch function of SVN or Git.

Comment: The option is in the "Advanced" tab on the m2eclipse importer screen... Works fine!