# How to obtain conflict-free maven multi-module projects that use the same version in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm facing kind of the same issue as explained in [Multiple versions of the same multi-modules maven project under eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445252/multiple-versions-of-the-same-multi-modules-maven-project-under-eclipse) except i'm in the need of having two checkouts of the same version:

- The snapshot that i'm currently working on for a major feature (with multiple modifications)
- That same snapshot to add some quick fixes of bugs i've found while working on that major feature.

The problem is that eclipse doesn't seem to pick the right workspace-resolved artifacts for either of the projects. One option i've found to force it to pick the right one is to close the other one. But I'd like to have both open so i can play with one or the other.

I could also do this in two different workspaces but that would mean having two instances of eclipse openened. I'd rather use that as a last resort.

Thanks

Comment: you have 2 modules that have the same name and the same version?

Comment: in the pom yes, they're stricly the same. In the workspace though they have two different names but eclipse doesn't care about that. It only looks for the artifact names apparently.

Comment: having 2 different modules with the same name and version (and probably groupId ?) but different content sound strange. Maybe you should rethink your project achitecture.

Comment: It's the same project, I 'm only checking it out twice to work on two differents thigs: one for a feature, the other one for a bug fix.